# Question About Momentum Flux Analysis Using Force Equations In Fluid Mechanics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, momentum, fluid-statics, non-newtonian-fluids

I was just revising fluid mechanics "Momentum Flux Analysis & Control Volumes" and I just noticed that there is an assumption in which we can assume to deal with gauge pressure instead of absolute pressure which is reasoned by that the atmospheric pressure cancels out since it acts on all directions of the control volume . Now coming to the force equations , some side areas may differ and thus even if the atmospheric pressure is the same if we multiplied it by each area we will get different forces and they won't cancel each other . How is that possible ? Here is an image below clarifying my issue ,see how areas differ at the inlet and outlet side for the flow ?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that if $P_1$ is represented as $P_1=P_{1,G}+P_{atm}$ (where P_{1,G} is the gauge pressure at point 1), then the $P_{atm}$ components all cancel, and you are left with a net pressure force of $P_{1,G}A_1$ at point 1.

Comment: yes you are true > but even though the force components wont cancel out in different areas because F=PA

Comment: Of course they will.  The forces cancel out vectorially.